# UnitOfWork: How to rollback and keep the logs

Tags: unit-of-work, transactionscope, aspnetboilerplate

I have a method as below:

```cs
using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
{
    var result = await ExcuteOperator(input);
    if (!result.WorkflowStatus) 
    {
        unitOfWork.Dispose();
    }
    unitOfWork.Complete();
}


public async Task<ExecuteOperatorOutput> ExcuteOperator(ExecuteOperatorInput input)
{                  
    //Doing something
    DoSomething(input);

    //Insert log
    await _logRepository.InsertAsync(logInput);

    //Recursive
    return await ExcuteOperator(input);
}
```

My question is: How to rollback the `unitOfWork` manually without throw exception before `unitOfWork.Complete()` and keep the inserted logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to rollback the `unitOfWork` manually.

See rationale/attempts: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues?q=rollback

That said, an interested reader is welcome to attempt and solve the issues.

> How to keep the logs after the transaction rolled back?

Begin a new `unitOfWork` that gets completed:

```cs
public async Task<ExecuteOperatorOutput> ExcuteOperator(ExecuteOperatorInput input)
{                  
    //...

    using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
    {
        await _logRepository.InsertAsync(logInput);
        unitOfWork.Complete();
    }

    //...
}
```